# Looking to create an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a solution to create an associative array from an flat array data in foreach loop:

What i have is a csv/xls file that has header on first row and data in next rows.

Row1: header
Row2,3,4,5: data

the array looks:

```
array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(7) {
            [0]=>
            string(3) "country"
            [1]=>
            string(7) "state"
            [2]=>
            string(3) "city"
            [3]=>
            string(5) "name"
            [4]=>
            string(4) "address"
            [5]=>
            string(6) "gender"
            [6]=>
            string(6) "status"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(7) {
            [0]=> 
            string(12) "Argentina"
            [1]=>
            string(12) "Corrientes"
            [2]=>
            string(12) "Corrientes"
            [3]=>
            string(12) "Jorge"
            [4]=>
            string(12) "Avenida Avellaneda 12"
            [5]=>
            string(12) "Masculino"
            [6]=>
            string(12) "Activo"
          }
          [2]=>
          array(7) {
            [0]=> 
            string(12) "Argentina"
            [1]=>
            string(12) "Chaco"
            [2]=>
            string(12) "Resistencia"
            [3]=>
            string(12) "Mariano"
            [4]=>
            string(12) "Avenida Peron 12"
            [5]=>
            string(12) "Masculino"
            [6]=>
            string(12) "Activo"
          }
        }
```

The result i need to get at the end is:

```
array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(7) {
            ['country']=> 
            string(12) "Argentina"
            ['state']=>
            string(12) "Corrientes"
            ['city']=>
            string(12) "Corrientes"
            ['name']=>
            string(12) "Jorge"
            ['address']=>
            string(12) "Avenida Avellaneda 12"
            ['gender']=>
            string(12) "Masculino"
            ['status']=>
            string(12) "Activo"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(7) {
            ['country']=> 
            string(12) "Argentina"
            ['state']=>
            string(12) "Chaco"
            ['city']=>
            string(12) "Resistencia"
            ['name']=>
            string(12) "Mariano"
            ['address']=>
            string(12) "Avenida Peron 12"
            ['gender']=>
            string(12) "Masculino"
            ['status']=>
            string(12) "Activo"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = $your_flat_array;

for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {

    $new_array[$i-1] = [];

    foreach ($array[$i] as $key => $value) {

        $new_array[$i-1][$array[0][$key]] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

> create a multidimensional array from an flat array

You already have a multidimensional array, because you got arrays in an array.

What you can do in this specific case is to use [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) in combination with [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

**Try this:**

```
$oldArray = array(
    array( "country", "state", "city", "name" ),
    array( "Argentina", "Corrientes", "Corrientes", "Jorge" ),
    array( "Argentina", "Chaco", "Resistencia", "Mariano" )
);

$newArray = array_splice( $oldArray, 1 );

foreach( $newArray as $index => $array ) {
    $newArray[$index] = array_combine( $oldArray[0], $array );
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $newArray );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["country"]=>
    string(9) "Argentina"
    ["state"]=>
    string(10) "Corrientes"
    ["city"]=>
    string(10) "Corrientes"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Jorge"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["country"]=>
    string(9) "Argentina"
    ["state"]=>
    string(5) "Chaco"
    ["city"]=>
    string(11) "Resistencia"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mariano"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the first item (header row) from your array:

```
 array_splice($yourArray, 0, 1);
```